# python netCDF4 module - how to get netCDF4.default_fillvals key for arbitrary numpy dtype?

Tags: python, netcdf4

I want to explicitly record the missing_value attribute for variables in a netCDF file I am writing with the netCDF4 module.  I am aware that I can [accomplish this by explicitly setting](https://github.com/Unidata/netcdf4-python/issues/94) the fill_value argument to [netCDF4.createVariable](https://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/#Dataset.createVariable), and that [netCDF4.default_fillvals](https://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/#Dataset.createVariable) provides the defaults.  So far so good.  Is there a reliable way to get the dict key for netCDF4.default_fillvals from an arbitrary numpy array?  The default_fillvals keys are ['i1', 'u1', ... 'i8', 'f8'], etc., and numpy dtypes are different and [potentially quite complex](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.dtypes.html).

I can make my own mapping dict, of course, but I suspect I'd miss some possibilities so I wonder if netCDF4 provides a better way.

Answer (score 0):

after some more thought I came up with the function below.  I'd still be all ears if there's a more elegant way to do this.

```
def _get_netCDF4_default_fillval(arr):
    """figure out netCDF4's default fill value for a numpy array

    netCDF4.default_fillvals provides the values.  It is a dict
    with keys S1, i1, u1, ... f4, f8.  numpy has a wide variety of
    dtype specifications
    (e.g. https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.dtypes.html);
    this function matches an arbitrary numpy array to a fill value
    using the array's dtype.

    ARGS:
       arr: array-like

    RETURNS:
       a fill value, either an integer, float, or string depending
          on the dtype of arr.
    """
    for k, v in netCDF4.default_fillvals.items():
        if arr.dtype is np.dtype(k):
            return(v)
    return(None)
```